# Iphone Application has got rejected many times

Tags: iphone

Iphone Application has got rejected many times. I am not find correct issue.

These are following issue in symbolicate

> Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread Thread 0
>   Crashed: 0   talentrack                       0x00000001000c5b18
>   specialized AppDelegate.application(UIApplication,
>   didFinishLaunchingWithOptions : [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool
>   (AppDelegate.swift:102) 1   talentrack
>     0x00000001000c29e4 @objc AppDelegate.application(UIApplication,
>   didFinishLaunchingWithOptiKons : [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool
>   (AppDelegate.swift:0)

Comment: You app is getting crashed. That's why apple is rejecting it

Comment: Ask Apple for the crash log, find the bug and fix it.

Comment: Have it worked in the simulator for the selected ios versions ?